# Prevent vim from indenting numbers wrongly

Tags: vim

I have vim without any special configuration and use it to edit my latex files. The following strange thing happens.

I have the following text types:

```
1234 people live in Hobit Land, Further Text, Further Text, Further Text
```

If I now type further until the line break occurs and type further, the following line is idented:

```
1234 people live in Hobit Land, Further Text, Further Text, Further Text
     and contiunes the line and further on....
```

Why is this the case? Its anoying because very time a line starts with a number (maybe even within text, only due to a linebreak before), the next text gets indented without sense.

How can I turn this of?

Comment: What configuration do you use? When I start vim with ´-u NONE` and set the textwidth to some value I do not observe the behaviour you're describing.

Comment: Yeah, you were right, I got a strange formatoption, just as the answer below correctly states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current formatting settings are configured to recognize numbered lists, which are basically just lines starting with a number.

Remove `n` from `'formatoptions'`. It's not a default setting, so you probably just need to modify `:set formatoptions=...` in your `.vimrc` file to remove `n`.

See `:help 'formatoptions'` and `:help fo-table` for details.